# can not check JSON request php

Tags: php, json, api, request

I am working with an API, when I will send them a request they will send me a JSON request to a link that I provided to them.

To check the request I wrote this line of codes

```
if(isset($_REQUEST)){
  file_put_contents('file.txt', json_encode($_REQUEST) , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

But when  check the file.txt, It just saves

```
[]
```

Why it just brings an empty double brackets instead the request?

Comment: Why are you using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET`/`$_POST`? You know that `$_REQUEST` include cookies too right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed by removing the check for the request and getting the content

```
$body = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents('file.txt', $body , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 1):

isset() is true even if an array has no elements, try this

```
if( !empty($_REQUEST) )
```